# why when store data from sqlplus the data show as entered but when insert from java the data show as?

Tags: java, sql

please help me,, The data show as a ????? when insert to the database from java
But when insert same query from the sqlplus 10g database the data show as a مرحبا

```
OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection();
    Connection conn = connect.oracleConn();
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "insert into testinsert (ssn) values ('مرحبا') ";
    statement.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println("success");
```

the data display from database as a ???? after implement above java code

But when insert data from sqlplus 10g itself

```
insert into testinsert (ssn) values ('مرحبا')
```

the data display from database as a مرحبا

**Thanks,,,,**

Comment: What is the data type of that column?

Comment: Varchar @JimMacaulay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the console encoding to utf-8

Go to Run -> Run Configurations..
In the Launch Configuration dialog, choose utf-8 on the Common tab.

[image]